# calculations imprecise, Redshift, postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am wondering why I am getting imprecise results even though I did type casting.

```
select (sum(sellerid)::decimal/count(*)::decimal) from winsales
```

This is the example from the Redshift documentation.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_examples.html

It should be giving something like 2.454545, but it truncates the value to 2.45.
Why is that and how can I increase the precision? Tried both float4 and float8 and get the same result.

Comment: maybe try `decimal(presicion, scale)` (or numeric) instead with a fixed precision and scale.

Comment: Have just tried. It changes nothing, still 2 digits after the point.

Comment: That's probably your SQL client limiting the number of decimals.

Comment: I am using SQL Workbench for postgresql. Do you know how to unlimit it to see the real data and not the reformatted?

Comment: http://sql-workbench.net/manual/options.html#options-decimal-digits

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select (sum(sellerid*1.0)/count(*)) from winsales
```